# Inspect intents at runtime?

Tags: android

I'm interested in inspecting an [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) (namely it's extras) that gets logged like this:

```
01-05 13:00:29.192: INFO/ActivityManager(74): Starting activity: Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/29 cmp=com.android.camera/.ViewImage (has extras) }
```

Is there any standard way to do it?
The only option I can think so far is writing a custom `IntentFilter` to catch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, to be able to see the extras, a custom intent filter would be the only thing I can think of that would allow you to inspect them at runtime.  You can look at the Android source to find out what extras are accepted by different activities.

Comment: Yeah, unless it goes like `intent = new Intent(this, ViewImage.class);`. Great we have the sources.

Answer (score 2):

Use something along the lines of:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
for (String key : bundle.keySet()){
 Log.d("Foo", "Extra " + key + " -> " + bundle.get(key));
}
```